# can i use parseInt to solve this problem? control flow

Tags: javascript

Prompt the user for a number that is greater than 100 but less than 2000 and store this as a variable named user.

Write an if statement that checks to see if user is greater than 100 and less than 2000.

If it is then it should assign message1 to a variable named result. If it is not then it should assign message2 instead.

```
var user = prompt("Give me a number between 100 and 2000");
var message1 = 'You are amazingly correct!';
var message2 = 'Awww, it looks like that number is not correct. Try again!';

var result = message1;
function 
if(){
 console.log(result);
}
else (sonsole.log(message2));
```

Comment: We are not doing your homework for you. So what is your issue? It is a simple comparison. I am sure the lecture material covered it.

Comment: i don't know how to use the parseInt method to basically choose a between100 and 2000. i started doing the problem myself and got stuck

Comment: Using your favorite search engine with "JavaScript convert string to number" would probably show what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var user = prompt("Give me a number between 100 and 2000");
var message1 = 'You are amazingly correct!';
var message2 = 'Awww, it looks like that number is not correct. Try again!';


if(user <2000 && user >100){
console.log(message1);
}else{
console.log(message2);
}
```

Comment: I thought this was a supportive community to get some help

Comment: @Cole It is, but you have to do your part first (search, research,...). How to use `parseInt` is a matter of seconds with Google/Bing/... And your "question" only contains a homework requirement with (pseudo-)code that won't run at all because of an obvious syntax error. And for this answer: SO has some rules on answers (and on questions as well), check the help section. One is that code only answers are discouraged. And also a part of your requirements is not fulfilled.